# Empty closing div at the beginning of loop surrounding a grouping

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

I don't even know what to search for, so what I've tried is not much since I'm stumped.

This is the loop, getting the month name and then grouping the events inside that month. The comment `//* Close the Div :` PROBLEM is where the issue is. The code does what it's supposed to do, but there is an empty div before the list.

```
if ( have_posts() ) : 

    $current_month = '';

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();


            if( $current_month != eo_get_the_start( 'm' ) ) :

                    $month = eo_get_the_start('F Y');

                    //* Close the Div : PROBLEM this is where it echos an empty closing div before first month name
                    echo '</div><!-- /events-by-month -->'; 

                    //* Start new group
                    echo '<h3 class="event-month" id="'. $month . '">' . $month . '</h3>';

                    //* Open div around the events in this month
                    echo '<div class="events-by-month" style="border:1px solid green">'; //* inline style so I can see

            endif;

                $current_month = eo_get_the_start('m');

                eo_get_template_part( 'eo-loop-single-event' );


    endwhile;


    //* Genesis Numbered Pagination
    genesis_numeric_posts_nav();

    else:

        echo '<p>'. __( 'No Events', 'joyful' ) . '</p>';

endif;
```

Comment: How about `echo !empty($current_month) ? '</div><!-- /events-by-month -->' : null;`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone *Hm....*, am starting to wonder if the answer I posted should be deleted. Edit: I deleted it, my bad.

Comment: If what @LawrenceCherone posted here in comments solved this, then let him know if it's to mark this one off as being solved. I was wrong earlier, an oversight on my part.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Feel free to add it to your answer ;p (If im right, hopefully we wont be left hanging)..

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks Lawrence, but it wouldn't be fair. You go for it ;-) it's all yours.

Comment: That is correct! Thank you so much, can you paste it into an answer please. Thank you!

Comment: @LawrenceCherone there, see? ^

Comment: @LawrenceCherone your comment is correct. Thank you. Please make an answer for me to select.

Comment: Np, done cheers, normally i'm wrong with wordpress related stuff :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while loop is going to initially loop once and echo out the closing tag before an initial opening tag has been echoed.

Simply checking that $current_month is not empty should fix it.

`echo !empty($current_month) ? '</div><!-- /events-by-month -->' : null;`

Comment: *"normally i'm wrong with wordpress related stuff"* - well, not this time.

Comment: Thank you. You are not wrong. I feel like a dummy, but then again, I am out of my comfort zone. I have to do this in order to style, I was just going to forget it and just wrap in jQuery, would have done it and then I could move on but it was bugging me.

Comment: No probs, glad to help.